# How can I batch execute multiple Gnosis Safe transactions via js/ts?

Tags: javascript, gnosis-safe, typescript

I've been using the typescript npm libs `gnosis.pm/safe-core-sdk` and `@gnosis.pm/safe-service-client` to execute Gnosis Safe transactions one-by-one. Recently I've noticed in the web UI that one can execute multiple Gnosis Safe transactions in one batch transaction. I'm not referring some kind of multi-send transaction that first needs to be created in a specific way but to executing already existing transactions that other users made and already signed.

Is this also possible via `safe-core-sdk` or using just `web3js` or `ethers` and how?
Is it also possible batch transactions coming from more than one Gnosis Safe in the same batch?

My goal is to automate execution and to save some gas fee costs via batching.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the MultiSend contract to batch execute `execTransaction` calls.

https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/main/contracts/libraries/MultiSend.sol